# How to get First 10 Values of array with json in php

Tags: php, json

This is an example of my JSON file.

```
{"Variable":"Hello","Variable1":20}, {"Variable":"Hi","Variable1":30},
{"Variable":"How","Variable1":40}, {"Variable":"Who","Variable1":50},
{"Variable":"Where","Variable1":60}, {"Variable":"This","Variable1":100},
{"Variable":"Pork","Variable1":10}, {"Variable":"Creep","Variable1":90},
{"Variable":"Mega Creeps","Variable1":80}, {"Variable":"LOL","Variable1":0},
{"Variable":"ROFL","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"LMAO","Variable1":0},
{"Variable":"POP","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"LOVE","Variable1":0},
{"Variable":"PICK","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"WHIZ","Variable1":0},
{"Variable":"BORED","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"KILLAH","Variable1":0},
{"Variable":"LOLLING","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"HALOO  HALOO","Variable1":0}
```

How can I get only the Top 10 from highest Variable1 number to the least? But gonna be passing the JSON file as the same format.

Comment: Sort the array by `Variable1`, then use `array_slice($array, 0, 10)` to get the first 10.

Comment: I suggest you to start learning the basics.

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file. You need to have `[` at the beginning and `]` at the end.

Comment: Can you show the code which you tried?

Comment: Thanks all for reply my question.. i already got it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will need to work with arrays, so convert your JSON to a PHP array by using `json_decode()`. Then you can get the X first values in the array by using `array_slice($array, 0, 10);`.

Using `usort()` with the spaceshipoperator `<=>`, you can sort on the `Variable1` property of the objects.

```php
$json = '[{"Variable":"Hello","Variable1":20}, {"Variable":"Hi","Variable1":30},
            {"Variable":"How","Variable1":40}, {"Variable":"Who","Variable1":50},
            {"Variable":"Where","Variable1":60}, {"Variable":"This","Variable1":100},
            {"Variable":"Pork","Variable1":10}, {"Variable":"Creep","Variable1":90},
            {"Variable":"Mega Creeps","Variable1":80}, {"Variable":"LOL","Variable1":0},
            {"Variable":"ROFL","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"LMAO","Variable1":0},
            {"Variable":"POP","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"LOVE","Variable1":0},
            {"Variable":"PICK","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"WHIZ","Variable1":0},
            {"Variable":"BORED","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"KILLAH","Variable1":0},
            {"Variable":"LOLLING","Variable1":0}, {"Variable":"HALOO  HALOO","Variable1":0}]';

// Get the JSON to a PHP array
$array = json_decode($json);

// Sort the array
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $b->Variable1 <=> $a->Variable1;
});

// Slice it, getting the first 10 elements
$parts = array_slice($array, 0, 10);

// Encode it back to JSON
echo json_encode($parts);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/WkiG0

Answer (score 2):

First we need to turn this JSON into array:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true)
```

Then we have to sort the array to get the top 10:

```
function sortByOrder($a, $b) {
    return $a['Variable1'] - $b['Variable1'];
}
usort($array, 'sortByOrder');
```

Then we get the top 10:

```
$array = array_slice($array, 0, 10);
```

then we have to convert back to JSON:

```
echo json_encode($array)
```